# How long does the League of Legends season last?

Tags: league-of-legends

I would like to know how it lasts; is that one year? or something?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pendragon announced that the start of Season 1 was on July 13, 2010. Season 1 was ended on August 23, 2011.

Season Two began on November 29, 2011, a week after the release of patch V1.0.0.130.
The season was scheduled to conclude on 6 November 2012, but was extended and officially concluded on 12 November 2012.

Season 3 began on Februar 1, 2013.
So, for this season as well, I believe that a season in League of Legends takes about a year. It's not exactly a year, but it'll come close to it. It also depends on the championship series around it.

PCGamer had the following to say about Season 3:

> The season lasts for 10 weeks and features the eight best teams from
>   last year’s North American and European qualifiers vying for the glory
>   of competing in the World Championship later this year. The North
>   American teams face off on Thursdays starting at 1pm PST and Fridays
>   at 5pm PST, while European matches occur Saturdays and Sundays
>   starting at 18:00 CET.

Comment: TY for your answer. Is there a winner like a tournament?

Comment: Ofcourse you have your own ranking in which you can rise or fall. The same goes for team rankings. The top best teams get a place in the championship series next season. I've edited my post a bit to elaborate on that.

Comment: As an esport, Riot Games runs things in much a similar way to how traditional team sports are run. There are so many teams in the league which compete regularly during the season. At the end of the season there will be regional and then world championships.

Comment: What about solo queue? Is there a winner like in team queue?

Comment: Yes there is, but Championship Series aren't being held in solo queue. An end date will be given a few days beforehand, and you can compete for the highest ranking. You'll get fame and will be listed on the ranking history.

Answer (score 0):

10 weeks is what i heard from my friend who is challenger. I think that this is correct, but am not completely sure. I would double check, but according to my Challenger friend, this is the answer. Thanks so much for asking this question, otherwise I would never think of asking it of anyone